# how to show blank field on certain condition in input box

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have stored phone number in bigint in mysql table. by default it sets the field as 0.
When the page loads, all other input fields are blank but phone number field shows 0.
the only option i am left with is to make phone number field in database table to varchar.

how to show empty input field when phone number from database comes to 0?

```
    <tr>
        <td>Primary Phone</td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "primaryPhone" id="primaryPhone"
                    path="userContacts.primaryPhone"  maxlength="20" size="50" />     </td></tr>
```

Please help.

Comment: How do you display data from mysql to html? For example if you use php, you could easily mention if conditional, which would output blank for html.

Comment: I am using spring mvc. data is  binded in the form object. I missed path="userContact.primaryPhone". Updated the code abpve.

Comment: Do you have the query that gets the data from the database?

Comment: I am using hibernate load.

Comment: you can use if(condition, then, otherwise) in the query but I think you should make phone number field in database as varchar. you only need numeric type only if you going to do some mathematic calculations.